# Laravel validate

Tags: php, laravel

I am making an e-commerce app with Laravel & React. Within Laravel, I have a "Product" Model, routes to CRUD Products, and Controllers mapped to those routes. Here is the problem: the Store method on the ProductController only works if I do not use a validate method on the $request data. Can you see what is wrong with my validate method? Thanks.

```php
Models/Product.php: 
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'slug',
        'description', 
        'image',
        'brand',
        'category',
        'price' 
    ];
}

Controllers/ProductController.php: 
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        // $request->validate([
        //     'name' => 'required',
        //     'slug' => 'required',
        //     'description' => 'required', 
        //     'image' => 'required',
        //     'brand' => 'required',
        //     'category' => 'required',
        //     'price' => 'required' 
        // ]);

        return Product::create($request->all());
    }
}

routes/api.php: 
Route::post("/products", [ProductController::class, 'store']);
```

If I run the "store" method with the validate method, and without a required field for the model passed in $request, I get this error:

405 method not allowed;
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The POST method is not supported for route /. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Ideas?

Comment: How do you "run" the store method? browser? Postman?

Comment: Thunder Client in VS Code. All other CRUD routes (without validate) work fine in Thunder Client.

Comment: The validate looks fine. When validation fails, it should route back to the previous page, but with a GET request, not a POST request. Do you see a request history/log when you submit to `/products`?

Comment: I've seen tutorials in which the validate method returns a more structured error response when something is missing.

Comment: It depends on the type of request. If the request is coming from a browser, it will redirect to the previous page with an error bag. If the request is an ajax call, it will return the failure messages. So it depends on what Thunder Client is sending for the type of response expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the route is defined as POST and also called as POST, then you can try to:

```
php artisan route:cache
```